# Disk Size Modification in Softlayer Affect loss of data in a disk is it true?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Disk Size Modification in Softlayer Affect loss of data in a disk is it true?
 I get an message During Disk Size Modification in my Virtual Machine they shows modify size Disk cause loss of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, the data will lost. Probably the best options could be:

> 1. Add a new disk to your vm
> 2. Detach the disk that you want to do an upgrade and add a new one. In this case the data will be preserved in the disk detached

These are the possible solutions in order to preserve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you increase/decrease the size of a secondary drive on a VSI, it removes and destroys the original and then attaches the new drive.